# where is Session.setDefault Location

Tags: meteor

Hello I am new in Meteor.

I saw [this](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session_set_default) api documentation.

before I knew Session.setDefault,

use default session setting inside Meteor.startup()

```
if(Meteor.startup(){
    Session.set("isArchive", false);
}
```

is this code are exactly same with Session.setDefault(key, value)??

Comment: Beware of your syntax, the correct one is `Meteor.startup()` (lowercase u)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are not the same. Values stored in `Session` survives hot code pushes, so if you use `Session.set` to initialize "variables", all "variables" will be re-assigned their default values on hot code pushes. With `Session.setDefault`, they will keep the value they had before the hot code push.

Comment: thanks for your answer.
in your opinion, I use Session.setDefault() for initializing my application?

Comment: @ChangJooPark Yea, that's its purpose.